# Loosing data using st_join

Tags: r, r-sf

I am trying to perform a spatial join of two sf shape files.I am losing all information from the second data set (i.e `output_inmap`). Whichever dataset is placed second will return all NA values. Anyone know what could be happening?

```
output_inmap <- st_read("processed/ceidars_data_inmap.shp")
output_inmap <-st_transform(output_inmap, crs=3310)

unzip("census-tract.zip")
census_tracts <- st_read("census-tract/tl_2019_06_tract.shp")

st_transform(census_tracts, crs = 3310)
st_transform(output_inmap, crs = 3310)

TC_1<- st_join(census_tracts, output_inmap)
```

I am losing all information from the second data set (i.e `output_inmap`). Whichever dataset is placed second will return all NA values. Anyone know what could be happening?

Comment: Hard to say unless you post a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-examplehttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: What are the types of the datasets? st_join works if both classes are sf objects. I use geo_join {tigris} to join spatial data with dataframes.

Comment: @SusanSwitzer, they are both sf objects, but I will try geo_join()

Comment: @BillO'Brien, you are right sorry, I am transitioning from being a passive user of Stack to an active member. The question is updated with more information.

Comment: Not sure what's happening there, but `st_transform()` does not modify anything in place, so you need to write back to the original variable. Also maybe your shape files are in fact non-overlapping. Can you check for validity of your shapes `sf::st_is_valid()`?

Comment: @dmi3kno, st_is_valid() is coming up as valid. I tried to specify the crs in the st_read() but still having the same issue          ```output_inmap <- st_read("processed/ceidars_data_inmap.shp", crs = 4269)
census_tracts <- st_read("census-tract/tl_2019_06_tract.shp", crs = 4269)```

Comment: Hey, I'm having the exact same problem, were you able to fix it? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Your second `st_transform` (of the census tracts) seems to be leading nowhere; consider this code (slightly adjusted via `dplyr` style pipe) to ensure both spatial objects are on the same CRS.

You may also consider setting parameter left of the `sf::st_join()` call (by default true) to false = change behaviour from left (preserving) to inner (filtering) style join. Sometimes this makes for a more concise code.

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

output_inmap <- st_read("processed/ceidars_data_inmap.shp") %>%
   st_transform(crs=3310)

unzip("census-tract.zip")
census_tracts <- st_read("census-tract/tl_2019_06_tract.shp") %>%
   st_transform(crs = 3310)


TC_1<- st_join(census_tracts, output_inmap)
```

Comment: I tried that code and I am still loosing data from the second data input in the st_join.

Comment: `STATEFP COUNTYFP TRACTCE       GEOID    NAME             NAMELSAD MTFCC
1       06      037  139301 06037139301 1393.01 Census Tract 1393.01 G5020  FUNCSTAT   ALAND AWATER    INTPTLAT     INTPTLON field_1 CARB_ID latitude
1         S 2865657      0 +34.1781538 -118.5581265      NA      NA       NA  longitude NH3 PM2_5 NOx SOx VOC height diam temp velocity
1         NA  NA    NA  NA  NA  NA     NA   NA   NA       NA  geometry
1  MULTIPOLYGON (((-118.5715 3...`

Comment: And are you 100% certain your objects are overlapping? What does `mapview::mapview(census_tracts) + mapview::mapview(output_inmap)` show?